# Wrong number of instances in custom generator to train a CNN (python)

Tags: python

I created a custom generator to train my CNN model in python.  Each instance of this generator has an image and array of 28 columns.

I'm using a batch size of 16 and there are 20215 instances inside the generator. However, I can not access them all.
First I determined the size of the generator by doing:

```
def __len__(self):
     return int(np.floor(len(self.list_IDs) / self.batch_size))
```

This returns the size as 20215/16=1263. However, 1263*16=20208, so there are 7 instances(images+arrays) that will not be used in the training. To fix that I did:

```
def __len__(self):
     return math.ceil(len(self.list_IDs) / self.batch_size)
```

But now it gives 1264*16=20224, which is 9 instances over my limit.

Is there a way I can guarantee that only 20215 are used in the training?

PS: The remaining code of my generator:

```
class DataGenerator_val(Sequence):
    
    def __init__(self, list_IDs, labels,metadata,batch_size=32, dim=(224,224), n_channels=3,
     n_classes=8, shuffle=True):
         #Initialization
         self.dim = dim
         self.batch_size = batch_size
         self.labels = labels
         self.metadata = metadata
         self.list_IDs = list_IDs
         self.n_channels = n_channels
         self.n_classes = n_classes
         self.shuffle = shuffle
         self.on_epoch_end()
         
    def on_epoch_end(self):
      self.indexes = np.arange(len(self.list_IDs))
      if self.shuffle == True:
        np.random.shuffle(self.indexes)

    def __len__(self):
     return math.ceil(len(self.list_IDs) / self.batch_size)

 
    def __data_generation(self, list_IDs_temp):
     #Generates data containing batch_size samples’ # X : (n_samples, *dim, n_channels)
     # Initialization
     X = np.empty((self.batch_size, *self.dim, self.n_channels))
     y = np.empty((self.batch_size), dtype=int)
     xMetadata = np.empty((self.batch_size, 28), dtype=int)
    # Generate data
     for i, ID in enumerate(list_IDs_temp):
     # Store sample
        auxImg = (cv2.imread("model_a_custom/val/"+ ID,cv2.IMREAD_COLOR))
        auxImg = cv2.cvtColor(auxImg,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)      
        auxImg=auxImg/255
        
        X[i,] = np.array(auxImg)
        # Store class
        y[i] = np.array(self.labels[ID])
        aux_meta=np.array(self.metadata[ID])
        xMetadata[i,] =np.array(aux_meta)
     return [X,xMetadata], tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y, num_classes=self.n_classes)
    
    def __getitem__(self, index):
     #Generate one batch of data’
     # Generate indexes of the batch
     indexes = self.indexes[index*self.batch_size:(index+1)*self.batch_size]
    # Find list of IDs
     list_IDs_temp = [self.list_IDs[k] for k in indexes]
    # Generate data
     [X,xMetadata], y = self.__data_generation(list_IDs_temp)
     return [X,xMetadata], y
```